# How to find RadComboBox in a GridTemplateColumn from a different GridTemplateColumn Radcombobox OnSelectedIndexChanged event

Tags: telerik, radcombobox

I have two GridTemplateColumn(s) which each contain a RadCombobox. When the left combobox OnSelectedIndexChanged event fires, I need to repopulate the right combobox according to the new value in the left. I cant seem to FindControl in any way from the event.

```
            <telerik:GridTemplateColumn HeaderText="CAKE Verticals" ItemStyle-Width="100px">
                <ItemTemplate>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <telerik:RadComboBox runat="server" ID="RadComboBox_CakeVerticals"  EnableLoadOnDemand="True"
                        OnItemsRequested="RadComboBox_CakeVerticals_ItemsRequested" AutoPostBack="true"
                        HighlightTemplatedItems="true" Height="140px" Width="220px" DropDownWidth="420px"
                        OnSelectedIndexChanged="RadComboBox_CakeVerticals_OnSelectedIndexChangedHandler">
                    </telerik:RadComboBox>
                </EditItemTemplate>
            </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
            <telerik:GridTemplateColumn UniqueName="CakeColumns" HeaderText="CakeColumns" ItemStyle-Width="100px">
                <ItemTemplate>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <telerik:RadComboBox runat="server" ID="RadComboBox_CakeColumns" EnableLoadOnDemand="True"
                        OnItemsRequested="RadComboBox_CakeColumns_ItemsRequested" AutoPostBack="true"
                        HighlightTemplatedItems="true" Height="140px" Width="220px" DropDownWidth="420px"
                        OnSelectedIndexChanged="RadComboBox_CakeColumns_OnSelectedIndexChangedHandler">
                    </telerik:RadComboBox>
                </EditItemTemplate>
            </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
```

and in the CS

```
protected void RadComboBox_CakeVerticals_OnSelectedIndexChangedHandler(object sender, RadComboBoxSelectedIndexChangedEventArgs e)
{
    RadComboBox combobox = (RadComboBox)RadGrid_Columns.FindControl("RadComboBox_CakeColumns");
    Session["verticalID"] = e.Value;

    RCB_CAKE_Columns_Populate(e.Value, combobox);

}
```

the problem is that combobox is always null.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem like this

```
    RadComboBox RCB_Verticals = sender as RadComboBox;

    GridDataItem item = (GridDataItem)RCB_Verticals.NamingContainer;

    RadComboBox combobox = (RadComboBox)item.FindControl("RadComboBox_CakeColumns");
```

It was just a matter of following the hierarchy of the NamingContainer, to the row level.